# How to make default value in angularjs dropbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work on my angularjs project.
I have select dropdown element:

```
<select ng-model="register.countryId" 
        ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in register.countries">
<option value = -1 selected>All items</option>
            </select>
```

And this array of object that populate the drop down element:

```
      $scope.register.countries = [{
          id: "1",
          name: "India"
      }, {
          id: "2",
          name: "USA"
      }, {
          id: "3",
          name: "UK"
      }, {
          id: "4",
          name: "Nepal"
      }];
```

Here is [planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z9yB7u5oI97O7rzQ1Vm2?p=preview).

How do I make this default value:

```
<option value = -1 selected>All items</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your model with that default value and angularjs will show that option selected by default. In your controller:

```
  $scope.register.countries = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "India"
  }, {
      id: "2",
      name: "USA"
  }, {
      id: "3",
      name: "UK"
  }, {
      id: "4",
      name: "Nepal"
  }];

  // Here you set your model's value
  $scope.register.countryId = $scope.register.countries[0].id;// 0 is index and will be replaced by index of default value in the array

  // This also works fine. And show selected option is india
  $scope.register.countryId = "1";
```

Comment: But I need to set default value that not inside countries array

Comment: You mean an option at very start as "Select Country" right ?